# Appending value to an array in solidity

Tags: solidity

I want to ask whether a dynamic size storage array in solidity is like an ArrayList in Java? (in inserting data)

For example, if I push(value) to the array, will it overwrite my original data? or is it simply just append it to the end no matter what is the size originally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Solidity Documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html)

> Methods .push() and .push(value) can be used to append a new element at the end of the array, where .push() appends a zero-initialized element and returns a reference to it.

So yes, `.push()` and `.push(value)` can be compared to an ArrayList in Java. Pushing a value (or no value) will append it to the end of the array, not overwriting any data in the array.

It's worth noting that the way this works has changed slightly over time. Solidity versions older than 0.6.0 allowed you to manually update the `.length` of a dynamic array. This doesn't delete any data in storage, but `.length` is what is used for `.push()` and `.push(value)` to decide where to put the data. As of Solidity version 0.6.0, `.length` has become read only and can't be manually updated.

As an example, if the array [1,2,3,4] is stored, `.length` would read as 4. If you update `.length` to 3, the 4 would still be in storage, but pushing to the array would overwrite the 4 in storage. Depending on how you look at it, this could be considered "overwriting my original data". Again, not important unless you're using > 0.6.0, but still a neat bit of Solidity history.

Comment: Is it possible to append an array directly to another array or do I have to do it element by element? Thanks!

Comment: @FalconStakepool You must append element by element